# What are Parse Html token methods for email templates in golang?

Tags: go, html-parsing, stringtokenizer

I am trying to create email templates having html tokens in golang. I have searched all over the web and found

```
"html/template"
```

library. It supports token format like below

```
Hello {{.Name}}
   <a href="{{.URL}}">Confirm email address</a>
```

But the requirement for html token is something like

```
Name: {{ test.name }}
Phone: {{ test.phone }}
Address: {{ test.address }}, {{ test.city }}, {{ test.state }} {{ test.zip }}
```

I could not found such token system in golang or any library supporting such format. Can anyone please tell how can I achieve to create such tokens. There should be no dot before the attribue. either it should be only the attribute like `{{Name}}` or like `{{ test.name }}`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a `$` before attribute names, you can use the template's `[with][1]` action. Something like:

```
tmpl :=`
{{ with $test := . }} 
Name: {{ $test.Name }}
Phone: {{ $test.Phone }}
Address: {{ $test.Address }}, {{ $test.City }}, {{ $test.State }} {{ $test.Zip }}
{{ end }}
`
```

Note that each struct field needs to be exported.